# Как в onSaveInstanceState() сохранить пользовательский объект

Tags: java, android

Как сохранить в `Bundle` пользовательский тип данных или `ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>`

Comment: а в чем проблема?

Comment: используйте [сериализацию или парселиализацию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34270358/7566397) для представления объектов в виде примитивов. Ваши данные должны реализовать интерфейс Parceble или Serializable